# What's the easiest way to escape HTML in Python?

Tags: python, html

cgi.escape seems like one possible choice.  Does it work well?  Is there something that is considered better?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

[`html.escape`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) is the correct answer now, it used to be [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) in python before 3.2. It escapes:

- `<` to `&lt;`
- `>` to `&gt;`
- `&` to `&amp;`

That is enough for all HTML.

EDIT: If you have non-ascii chars you also want to escape, for inclusion in another encoded document that uses a different encoding, like *Craig* says, just use:

```
data.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Don't forget to decode `data` to `unicode` first, using whatever encoding it was encoded.

However in my experience that kind of encoding is useless if you just work with `unicode` all the time from start. Just encode at the end to the encoding specified in the document header (`utf-8` for maximum compatibility).

Example:

```
>>> cgi.escape(u'<a>bá</a>').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'&lt;a&gt;b&#225;&lt;/a&gt;
```

Also worth of note (thanks Greg) is the extra *`quote`* parameter `cgi.escape` takes. With it set to `True`, `cgi.escape` also escapes double quote chars (`"`) so you can use the resulting value in a XML/HTML attribute.

EDIT: Note that cgi.escape has been deprecated in Python 3.2 in favor of [`html.escape`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape), which does the same except that *`quote`* defaults to True.

Comment: The additional boolean parameter to cgi.escape should also be considered for escaping quotes when text is used in HTML attribute values.

Comment: Just to be sure: If I run all untrusted data through the `cgi.escape` function, is enough to protect against all (known) XSS attacs?

Comment: @Tomas Sedovic: Depends on where you'll put the text after running cgi.escape in it. If placed in root HTML context then yes, you're completely safe.

Comment: What about input like {{Measures 12 Ω"H x 17 5/8"W x 8 7/8"D. Imported.}}
That's not ascii, so encode() will throw an exception at you.

Comment: @Andrew Kolesnikov: Have you tried it? `cgi.escape(yourunicodeobj).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace') == '{{Measures 12 &#937;"H x 17 5/8"W x 8 7/8"D. Imported.}}'` -- as you can see, the expression returns ascii bytestring, with all non-ascii unicode chars encoded using the xml character reference table.

Comment: Actually it would seem you need to do cgi.escape(yourunicode).decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'), otherwise the ascii codec doesn't know how to handle the Ω.

Comment: @AdrianGhizaru well, no. First of all, you're trying to .decode `yourunicode`, which, since you claim it is unicode, would be **already decoded**. That would invoke *implicity ascii encoding*, or fail directly, depending on python version. If you just use the example provided at the end of the answer `cgi.escape(u'Ω').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')` it will already work. So I guess that if you got an error, then `yourunicode` is not really unicode, you'd need to decode it first to get unicode.

Comment: how to ecape several whitespaces and linebraks?

Comment: Can you explain the decode/encode process in full? I get the error message "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 76: invalid start byte" when I try  `text.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace') `.. trying decode('Unicode') throws unknown encoding: Unicode

Comment: For anyone landing here trying to avoid XSS vulnerabilities, simple cgi escaping is definitely NOT enough to protect you, contrary to some earlier/ancient comments. See [this tricky case](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_JavaScript_escapes) for example. Note that `html.escape` will protect you from that vector, though (since it gets both quote types)... provided you use it everywhere.

Comment: NOTE: `cgi.escape` was removed in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 176):

In Python 3.2 a new [`html`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) module was introduced, which is used for escaping reserved characters from HTML markup.

It has one function `escape()`:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.escape('x > 2 && x < 7 single quote: \' double quote: "')
'x &gt; 2 &amp;&amp; x &lt; 7 single quote: &#x27; double quote: &quot;'
```

Comment: What about `quote=True`?

Comment: @SalmanAbbas Are you afraid that quotes aren't escaped? Note that `html.escape()` does escape quotes, by default (in contrast, `cgi.quote()` does not - and only escapes double quotes, if told so). Thus, I have to explicitly set an optional parameter to inject something into an attribute with `html.escape()`, i.e. to make it insecure for attributes: `t = '" onclick="alert()'; t = html.escape(t, quote=False); s = f'<a href="about.html" class="{t}">foo</a>'`

Comment: @maxschlepzig I think Salman is saying `escape()` is not enough to make attributes safe. In other words, this is not safe: `<a href=" {{ html.escape(untrusted_text) }} ">`

Comment: @pianoJames, I see. I consider checking link values a domain specific semantic validation. Not a lexical one like escaping. Besides inline Java Script, you really don't want to create links from untrusted user input without further URL specific validation (e.g. because of Spammers). A simple method to protect against inline Java Script in attributes like `href`  is to set a Content Security Policy that disallows it.

Comment: @pianoJames It is safe, because `html.escape` does escape single quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 12):

**If you wish to escape HTML in a URL:**

This is probably NOT what the OP wanted (the question doesn't clearly indicate in which context the escaping is meant to be used), but Python's native library [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) has a method to escape HTML entities that need to be included in a URL safely.

The following is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from urllib import quote

x = '+<>^&'
print quote(x) # prints '%2B%3C%3E%5E%26'
```

[Find docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)

Comment: This is the wrong kind of escaping; we're looking for [HTML escapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), as opposed to [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Encoding).

Comment: Nontheless - it was what I was actually looking for ;-)

Comment: In Python 3, this has been moved to urllib.parse.quote. https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting

Answer (score 10):

There is also the excellent [markupsafe package](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/markupsafe).

```
>>> from markupsafe import Markup, escape
>>> escape("<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>")
Markup(u'&lt;script&gt;alert(document.cookie);&lt;/script&gt;')
```

The `markupsafe` package is well engineered, and probably the most versatile and Pythonic way to go about escaping, IMHO, because:

1. the return (`Markup`) is a class derived from unicode (i.e. `isinstance(escape('str'), unicode) == True`
2. it properly handles unicode input
3. it works in Python (2.6, 2.7, 3.3, and pypy)
4. it respects custom methods of objects (i.e. objects with a `__html__` property) and template overloads (`__html_format__`).

Answer (score 7):

[`cgi.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) should be good to escape HTML in the limited sense of escaping the HTML tags and character entities.

But you might have to also consider encoding issues: if the HTML you want to quote has non-ASCII characters in a particular encoding, then you would also have to take care that you represent those sensibly when quoting. Perhaps you could convert them to entities. Otherwise you should ensure that the correct encoding translations are done between the "source" HTML and the page it's embedded in, to avoid corrupting the non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 7):

No libraries, pure python, safely escapes text into html text:

```
text.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('<', '&lt;'
        ).replace('\'','&#39;').replace('"','&#34;').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Comment: Your ordering is wrong, the `&lt;` will get escaped to `&amp;lt;`

Comment: @jason s Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 2):

Not the easiest way, but still straightforward. The main difference from **cgi.escape** module - it still will work properly if you already have `&amp;` in your text. As you see from comments to it:

- **`cgi.escape` version**

```py
def escape(s, quote=None):
    '''Replace special characters "&", "<" and ">" to HTML-safe sequences.
    If the optional flag quote is true, the quotation mark character (")
    is also translated.'''
    s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
    s = s.replace("<", "&lt;")
    s = s.replace(">", "&gt;")
    if quote:
        s = s.replace('"', "&quot;")
    return s
```

- **`regex` version**

```py
QUOTE_PATTERN = r"""([&<>"'])(?!(amp|lt|gt|quot|#39);)"""
def escape(word):
    """
    Replaces special characters <>&"' to HTML-safe sequences. 
    With attention to already escaped characters.
    """
    replace_with = {
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;',
        '&': '&amp;',
        '"': '&quot;', # should be escaped in attributes
        "'": '&#39'    # should be escaped in attributes
    }
    quote_pattern = re.compile(QUOTE_PATTERN)
    return re.sub(quote_pattern, lambda x: replace_with[x.group(0)], word)
```

Answer (score 1):

### `cgi.escape` extended

This version improves `cgi.escape`.  It also preserves whitespace and newlines.  Returns a `unicode` string.

```
def escape_html(text):
    """escape strings for display in HTML"""
    return cgi.escape(text, quote=True).\
           replace(u'\n', u'<br />').\
           replace(u'\t', u'&emsp;').\
           replace(u'  ', u' &nbsp;')
```

#### for example

```
>>> escape_html('<foo>\nfoo\t"bar"')
u'&lt;foo&gt;<br />foo&emsp;&quot;bar&quot;'
```

Answer (score 1):

For legacy code in Python 2.7, can do it via [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
>>> esub = EntitySubstitution()
>>> esub.substitute_html("r&d")
'r&amp;d'
```