# HTML Escaping in Python

Tags: python, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the easiest way to escape HTML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python)

What's the easiest way to HTML escape characters in Python? I would like to take a list of items and iterate over them, having them changed to HTML escaped characters.

Comment: I've considered string replacing, and I've also looked at this solution: http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml but none of these methods seem necessarily superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python standard library has `cgi` module, which provides `escape` function.

See: http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#functions

Answer (score 0):

Template engines tend to make your code cleaner and easier to maintain. For example, you can pass the list to the template engine and do the iteration inside the template:

```
t = Template('{% for item in items %}{{ item }}\n{% endfor %}')
result = t.render(dict(items=some_list))
```

Most template engines will escape html by default. There are quite a few to choose from, when I'm not  not using Django, may favorite is jinja2.

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating for other alternatives.

Comment: I don't want templating. I'll just HTML escape manually, but I was hoping for a module that would do it easily. I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: my advice is to avoid dealing with html escaping before presentation time.

Comment: This is right before presentation to the Twitter Search API

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: do you want to strip html tags or escape them (converting `>` to `&gt;`, for example)? BTW, would you like tho chat?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested, just a sample):

```
html_convert = {"<": "&lt;", ">": "&gt;", "\"": "&quot;", "&": "&amp;"} #Etc.
html_text = "<div id=\"idk\">Something truly interesting & fun...</div>"
html_list = [char for char in html_text]

for char in html_list:
    if char in html_convert:
        char = html_convert[char]

html_escaped_text = "".join(html_list)
```