# How to do HTML escaping in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to implement a function which replaces the following values:

```
# > with &gt;
# < with &lt;
# " with &quot;
# & with &amp
```

I keep getting an error with my function. What exactly is wrong?

```
def escape_html(s):
    data = list(s)
    if ">" in data:
        data.replace(">","&gt;") 
    if "<" in data:
        data.replace("<","&lt;") 
    if '"' in data:
        data.replace('"',"&quot;") 
    if "&" in data:
        data.replace("&","&amp;") 
    word = data.join()
    return word

print escape_html("<>")
```

Note: This is more of a fundamental programming question. My focus is the reason why my function isn't working. I cannot use outside libraries for this project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1061697/2870069, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3096948/2870069, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11336384/2870069 and others...

Comment: This is more of a fundamentals in programming questions rather than what is the most efficient way of solving the problem. I'm more worried about why my code doesn't work.

Comment: If this is all that you want to replace, use 'html escape' as others have suggested. However, if you want to stick with this method, you should replace & first, because new &'s are created when you replace in the first three cases.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape):

```
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape('<this & that>')
'&lt;this &amp; that&gt;'
```

If you use Python 3.2+, use [`html.escape`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) as documentation suggest:

> `cgi.escape`
>
> Deprecated since version *3.2*: This function is unsafe because `quote` is `false` by default, and therefore deprecated. Use `html.escape()` instead.

Comment: Could you please show an example where `quote` makes a difference?

Comment: @MartinThoma, `cgi.escape('"')` returns `'"'` while `html.escape('"')` returns `'&quot;'`.

Answer (score 4):

There are builtin functions to do that. You can use [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) if you are using Python 2.x. It is deprecated in Python 3.2. So, if you are using Python >= 3.2, you can use [`html.escape`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/html.html#html.escape)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `replace`, which is a bit more universal.

For example,

```
string = ">>>"
new_string = string.replace(">", "&gt;")
print new_string # '&gt;&gt;&gt;'
```

However, keep in mind that if you're trying to replace double quotes, you'd need to enclose them in single quotes, and vice-versa

Comment: There really is no need to be universal between Python 2x and 3x because the two aren't compatible in the first place

Comment: I just meant in the event that he wanted to replace something other than those 4 characters. I realize that the context is for dealing with HTML content, but just thought it might be worth nothing that HTML escape only works for those chars, and won't be helpful for any others

Comment: That's exactly why I voted you up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def escape_html(data):
    return data.replace("&","&amp;").replace('"',"&quot;").replace(">","&gt;").replace("<","&lt;")
```

Comment: Order of replace is important.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xml.sax.saxutils` which ships an `escape` method.
See [escaping HTML](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml).