# Table creating gets messed up

Tags: python, html

I am trying to create a table using the below HTML code in python,it works for most instances but for some cases the table gets messed up like below,please see screen shot..any inputs on what is wrong?how to debug it?any workarounds to fix it?really appreciate any inputs

HTML source for messed up row: http://pastie.org/8263837

[image]

```
  ...........
  ...........
  GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + GerritInfo['TargetName'].rstrip('\n') + "</td>"
  GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>" + GerritInfo['Assignee'].rstrip('\n') + "</td>"
  usernames.append(GerritInfo['Assignee'].rstrip('\n'))

  #Below is the block that is getting messed up
  GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td height=\"150\%\">"
  GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<table>"  
  for item in GerritInfo['GerritUrl']:
    GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<tr>"
    GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "<td>"
    GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + item.rstrip('\n/') + "<br>"
    GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "</td>"
    GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "</tr>"

  GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "</table>"
  GerritMailBody = GerritMailBody + "</td>"

  ............
  ............
```

Comment: Post input data and output HTML (**source**, not picture)

Comment: @MarioRossi - picture shows the output...i already shared the piece of source that is causing this..row no#5 should be in the same format as row #4 but as you can see it gets messed up.

Comment: @user2125827 he means the HTML output, not the visual output.  That is not useful

Comment: @ExplosionPills - screenshot is the HTML output..are you asking the HTMl source code?

Comment: @user2125827 yes the source, but the source is still output from the python code

Comment: Also, just showing us what `item` is for rows 4 and 5 would help a lot. One pretty likely problem is that there's HTML and/or unescaped angle brackets in the middle of item #5…

Comment: @all - HTML output for the messedup row is http://pastie.org/8263837

Comment: Use the power of the [template](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) Luke.

Comment: Note - I've rolled back your changes - it's not fair to "vandalise" your own posts like that - it invalidates the answers that people have spent time on providing you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing html this way in python is not readable at all and difficult to maintain. Switch to a template engine like [mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/):

```
from mako.template import Template
print Template("hello ${data}!").render(data="world")
```

Define an html file with your message body template, fill it with data via `render` and get the message as a string:

```
from mako.template import Template

mytemplate = Template(filename='body.html')
print mytemplate.render(data=data)
```

Trust me, this will make your life easier and sleep more peaceful.

---

Possible reason of the messed up HTML is that the data you are inserting into the html contains some characters (`<`, `<`, `&`) that should be escaped. Consider calling `cgi.escape()` on every item you are inserting. Also see: [What's the easiest way to escape HTML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python)

Again, escaping works out-of-the-box in most of the template engines out there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I cannot change the code now..need to get it working this way..complete code is  http://pastie.org/8263783 ..anything you can tell from the code

Comment: @user2125827 I bet the data you are inputting there has sometimes some characters that needs to be escaped.

Comment: @user2125827 and if you'll switch to `mako` - it'll make escaping for you :) Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to debug the issue:

1. Identify the conditions that cause the issue, especially dataset.
2. Reduce.  Remove information from the dataset until you have exactly what makes the program fail.
3. Debug the program with only that information.
4. Regress-test with the full dataset plus previous tests.

Comment: @user2125827  Nothing pops on first sight.

Comment: @ Mario - HTML output for the messedup row is pastie.org/8263837

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many problems with your HTML, but here's the most obvious one causing your issue at line 19:

`<td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'><table!></td>`

What's that `<table!>` "tag" doing there? Did you read the HTML it gave you before asking your question?

Comment: ya,that could be the one...any idea why that would have go there based on the code shared above?