# Preventing etree from resolving HTML entities when parsing HTML contents

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

Is there any way to prevent etree from resolving HTML entities when parsing HTML contents?

```
html = etree.HTML('<html><body>&amp;</body></html>')
html.find('.//body').text
```

This gives me '&' but I want to get '&amp;' itself.

Comment: One option/workaround is to process the body text with `cgi.escape`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pre/post process your data.
replace '&' with u'\xfe' before feeding to HTML parser and replace u'\xfe' with '&' when output.

```
from lxml import etree
html = etree.HTML('<html><body>&amp;</body></html>'.replace('&',u'\xfe'))
html.find('.//body').text.replace(u'\xfe','&')
u'&amp;'
```