# Prevent Python lxml from replacing entityref with actual character

Tags: python, html, lxml

I would like to retrieve the literal text from an xpath using lxml.  Unfortunately, it converts entityrefs as shown below:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML('<html><body><div>&amp;</div></body></html>')
text = tree.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]')[0].text
print(text)

>>> &
```

Is there some way to prevent the conversion or am I stuck having to back-convert it?

Comment: Similar questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/22263599/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687677/407651