# What is easiest way to escape html tags, except some of those similar Bold,

Tags: python, html, django

I need using a pythonic module/algorithm to escape only determined html tags, for example, suppose we have below html code:

```
<i>This</i> is an <b>example</b>
```

And we want convert to:

```
&lt;i&gt;This&lt;/i&gt; is an <b>example</b>
```

to present in html page similar below:

<i>This</i> is an **example**

How can i doing this, in easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Quick example:

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""
```

Instead, you can open the html file from your computer to avoid that ugly string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
# <html>
#  <head>
#   <title>
#    The Dormouse's story
#   </title>
#  </head>
#  <body>
#   <p class="title">
#    <b>
#     The Dormouse's story
#    </b>
#   </p>
#   <p class="story">
#    Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
#     Elsie
#    </a>
#    ,
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
#     Lacie
#    </a>
#    and
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link2">
#     Tillie
#    </a>
#    ; and they lived at the bottom of a well.
#   </p>
#   <p class="story">
#    ...
#   </p>
#  </body>
# </html>
```

And then:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
# http://example.com/elsie
# http://example.com/lacie
# http://example.com/tillie
```

In your case, you search for a 'b' tag or an 'i' tag, but the same logic applies.
The documentation goes further in how to use this library.
I hope this will be useful to you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this algorithm are realy useful but i think, maybe i found easiest way for doing this. i'm lazy :)

Comment: You can simply read the file, look for ocurrences of your pattern using regular expressions (re or regex module can help you), and replace whatever you want and rewrite the file or write a new one with the changes.

Comment: Yeah, but if for this issue already created an module, i preference use this, maybe i find a function that get html code and except tags list and return my ideal result: `escape_except(html_code, ['b'])`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python) is another module: cgi and it has a function called escape. Maybe that one is what are you looking for.