# Python: Escaping HTML tags without space after each opening/closing tag

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I am trying to escape HTML characters but the best effect which I achievied is html string but with spaces after each html opening/closing tag:

`< b >< i > TEST < /b > < /i >`

but I need:
`<b><i> TEST </b></i>` so it can be seen by the browser.

What I did:

1. no effect:

`h = HTMLParser()
comment = h.handle_data("<b><i>Try it:</b></i>")`

2. this is my best resoult but it has spaces after each html special character

`h = HTMLParser()
comment = h.unescape("&lt b &gt &lt i &gt TEST: &lt /b &gt &lt /i &gt")`

3. no effect too

`h = HTMLParser()
comment = h.unescape("&lt;b&gt;&lt;i&gt; TEST: &lt;/b&gt;&lt;/i&gt;")`

Comment: This has been answered here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python

Comment: @jaime yes, but in same cases it changes `<` to `&lt;` sometimes not

Comment: @jaime it doesn't work for link e.g. `cgi.escape("<a href="http://link.com">link</a>"` the result will be: `&lt;a href="http://link.com"&gt;link&lt;/a&gr;`. Can you tell my why is that, please?

Comment: That is correctly escaped.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: I mean sometimes in the result string I got `<` sometimes `&lt;`. Nothing wrong, just curious about that

Comment: can you give an html string that doesn't work the way you expect it to?

Comment: I said in previous comment that everything is working but the viusally effect in string is different