# Use input in mail - Python

Tags: python, email, python-3.10

I am prompting a user for input, but I have no idea how to include it in a python mail. This is the message field:

```
message = """\ 
Subject: Info
{input} """
```

The input is supposed to be where I put `{input}`, how do I implement it?

Comment: Use a f-string? `input = 'abc' ; message = f'''xxx{input}xxx'''`

Comment: For security reasons, make sure you clean (escape) the string before to insert it in your email.  Otherwise your user could do XSS injection, or other attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an fstring since python 3.6 (just put a `f` before the `"""`), but don't forget to escape the content of the input for security reasons. Here is an example with the [html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) module, available since python 3.2 :

```py
import html
# ...
message = f"""
Subject: Info
{html.escape(input)}
"""
```

Otherwise the old way is to use `.format()`:

```
import html
# ...
message = f"""
Subject: Info
{}
""".format(html.escape(input))
```

if you are below version 3.2, then you can escape the input [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49329235/17965313):

> ```py
>  text.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('>', '&gt;'
>     ).replace('<','&lt;').replace('\'','&#39;'
>     ).replace('"','&#34;').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
> ```

But except if you have heavy restrictions on python version, you should be using a recent version of `python 3`.

you can check your python version with `python --version` and/or `python3 --version`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the f-string formatting method, introduced with Python 3.6.

```
message = f"""\ 
Subject: Info
{input()} """
```