# Replace chars in substring of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm working on a blog with Django, however my question is Python related not really Django related.

To write my blog posts I use Quill which generate the post in HTML. I save this HTML in the database than display the post using the filter |safe. Until now everything worked well until ... I want to display HTML code as examples which is obviously considered as safe because of the filter and is interpreted by the browser.

As a workaround I try to create a function able to escape HTML code as soon as they are between the tags  but not escape the HTML out of this tag.

For example if quill return this:

```
<p> This is the code you need:
<pre class="myclass"> <div> The code </div> </pre>
</p>
```

I would like to save in database something like this:

```
<p> This is the code you need:
<pre class="myclass"> &lt;div&gt; The code &lt;/div&gt; </pre>
</p>
```

That way the safe tag will make the HTML code interpreted and display the HTML code inside the  tag.

My problem is I don't find a way to make a replacement for each character only between the tags and keep everything as it is.

Basically I try to replace characters only in a substring of a string.

I'm running on python3.10

Any idea?

Comment: You can use an HTML parser such as `html.parser` or BeautifulSoup, modify the tree accordingly and output it back to a string.

Comment: How do you define which part you want to escape

Comment: @Thomas I'll have a look to this thanks

Comment: @sudden_appearance All the code to escape is between the <pre></pre> tags

Comment: Then there is `cgi.escape` thing already inside python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to escape HTML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python)

Comment: It does not really answer my problem. I know how to escape HTML tags. My problem is more how to escape some parts and not others.

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python)

You can use either `cgi.escape` or `html.escape`

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @accdias, what's wrong? I attached the link to question with 2 well written answers and summed up the total here. I guess no need to rewrite same thing twice.

Comment: Read the article and judge by yourself. If you think it is a duplicate, flag the question as such and add a comment to the main thread. Posting an "answer" just to say that is not a good answer at all.